# XML not parsing as expected with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse XML from a website.  I have no control over the content if it’s not formatted properly.  A very simplified example of the XML data is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<items:items itemId="1">
    <parameter name="param1" value="A"/>
    <parameter name="param2" value="B"/>
    <product productid="test1">
        <parameter name="prodinfo1" value="Q"/>
        <parameter name="prodinfo2" value="R"/>
    </product>
    <product productid="test2">
        <parameter name="prodinfo1" value="S"/>
        <parameter name="prodinfo2" value="T"/>
    </product>
</items:items>
<items:items itemId="2">
    <parameter name="param1" value="C"/>
    <parameter name="param2" value="D"/>
    <product productid="test3">
        <parameter name="prodinfo1" value="U"/>
        <parameter name="prodinfo2" value="V"/>
    </product>
    <product productid="test4">
        <parameter name="prodinfo1" value="W"/>
        <parameter name="prodinfo2" value="X"/>
    </product>
</items:items>
```

I wrote a short Python 2.7 script using BeautifulSoup 3.2.1 to parse the XML (I am constrained to using these versions, so unfortunately upgrading is not an option).

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup

def main():
    fieldList = ('param1','param2')
    prodFieldList = ('prodinfo1','prodinfo2')
    xmlfile = 'test.xml'
    xmldata = open(xmlfile).read()
    soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(xmldata)
    print soup.prettify()

    for message in soup.findAll('items:items', recursive=False):
        report = {}
        for field in fieldList:
            report[field] = '{}'.format(message.find(attrs={"name" : field})['value'])
        for product in message.findAll('product', recursive=False):
            prodreport = {}
            for field in prodFieldList:
                prodreport[field] = '{}'.format(product.find(attrs={"name" : field})['value'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

For some reason, the parameters within `<product></product>` such as prodinfo1 and prodinfo2 do not show up.  When I look at the output from `soup.prettify()`, rather than indenting as displayed in my XML file above, I can see that the product parameters are being listed outside the `<product></product>` tags, and thus their identity with a particular product is lost:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<items:items itemid="1">
 <parameter name="param1" value="A">
 </parameter>
 <parameter name="param2" value="B">
  <product productid="test1">
  </product>
 </parameter>
 <parameter name="prodinfo1" value="Q">
 </parameter>
 <parameter name="prodinfo2" value="R">
  <product productid="test2">
  </product>
 </parameter>
 <parameter name="prodinfo1" value="S">
 </parameter>
 <parameter name="prodinfo2" value="T">
 </parameter>
</items:items>
<items:items itemid="2">
 <parameter name="param1" value="C">
 </parameter>
 <parameter name="param2" value="D">
  <product productid="test3">
  </product>
 </parameter>
 <parameter name="prodinfo1" value="U">
 </parameter>
 <parameter name="prodinfo2" value="V">
  <product productid="test4">
  </product>
 </parameter>
 <parameter name="prodinfo1" value="W">
 </parameter>
 <parameter name="prodinfo2" value="X">
 </parameter>
</items:items>
```

I have been searching but haven’t found anyone with the same problem.  Why is this happening, and what can I do to properly parse this XML?  Thank you for your time.

Comment: What you have in the question is not XML since there is no root element (and no declaration of the `items` namespace prefix).

Comment: I can reproduce the problem. For what it's worth, it does work with BeautifulSoup 4.

Comment: Thanks @mzjn.  I tried adding a root element by surrounding all the quasi-XML after the `<?xml>` line within `<container></container>` tags, but it made no difference.  I was also able to get it to work with BeautifulSoup4 at home, but at work we don't have it available.  Very strange - maybe a bug in BS3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me after making 3 changes:

- 0) I'm using bs4 (this is the only version I have installed)
- 1)  `BeautifulSoup(xmldata, features="xml")` instead of `BeautifulStoneSoup(xmldata)`, `BeautifulStoneSoup` is depreciated in bs4
- 2) I changed `soup.findAll('items:items', recursive=False)` to `soup.findAll(True, {"itemId":True}, recursive=False)`

  ```
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

  xmldata = #load your data 

  if __name__ == "__main__":

      fieldList = ('param1','param2')
      prodFieldList = ('prodinfo1','prodinfo2')
      soup = BeautifulSoup(xmldata, features="xml")# <- notice this
      print soup.prettify(), "\n"

      for message in soup.findAll(True, {"itemId":True}, recursive=False):# <- and this

          report = {}
          for field in fieldList:
              report[field] = '{}'.format(message.find(attrs={"name" : field})['value'])
              print report

          for product in message.findAll('product', recursive=False):
              prodreport = {}
              for field in prodFieldList:
                  prodreport[field] = '{}'.format(product.find(attrs={"name" : field})['value'])
              print prodreport
  ```

output:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <items itemId="1">
     <parameter name="param1" value="A"/>
     <parameter name="param2" value="B"/>
     <product productid="test1">
      <parameter name="prodinfo1" value="Q"/>
      <parameter name="prodinfo2" value="R"/>
     </product>
     <product productid="test2">
      <parameter name="prodinfo1" value="S"/>
      <parameter name="prodinfo2" value="T"/>
     </product>
    </items> 

    {'param1': 'A'}
    {'param2': 'B', 'param1': 'A'}
    {'prodinfo1': 'Q', 'prodinfo2': 'R'}
    {'prodinfo1': 'S', 'prodinfo2': 'T'}
```

Comment: Thanks Logan, this findAll method could come in handy in the future.  I was finally able to get bs4 in my environment which worked as you and @mzjn suggested.  I guess bs3 must have a bug.